# Work around the lack of templates in java

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

In C++ I build a little wrapper around cout like this:

```
template <class T>
void output( T a ){
   if(is_this_enabled==true)
      std::cout<<a<<endl;
   return;
}
```

When certain kinds of output flood the command-line, I'd only need to change `is_this_enabled` and I can suppress them in one stop when they weren't relevant. 

 I'm new to java, and I started writing a class to accomplish the same ends. I found myself reviewing the tutorials and seeing that there's no *direct* analog to templates in java.
Is there a better/shorter way to do this then writing accompanying <strike>functions</strike> methods for each of`System.out.println()`'s overloads? Generics don't seem to do it.

Comment: Read about generics in Java.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @MrEricSir I basically wanted to do what I the given C++ code did but in java. Works now.

Comment: @Eran Generics can't do what is required. My simple understanding is that wildcards and generics narrow how a class can be treated within a method/class in order to avoid the sort of checking that C++ templates require (which java can't do because of the way it delays compiling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a feature known as autoboxing--when a primitive is assigned to a variable or field of a reference type, it is converted into an instance of that type (e.g. `int` becomes `java.lang.Integer`.

Since the act of printing an object implies `toString()` being called, you can simply have a method:

```
void output(Object o){
    if(outputEnabled)
        System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

Comment: It should be warned that autoboxing of primitives is a slow process that should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @Smith_61 Do you have a benchmark showing how slow it is?

Comment: I do not personally have any valid benchmarks, but there is an article from oracle about the potential performance hits. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: Performance isn't an issue, final version won't have command-line. Going to give this a try now.

Comment: As long as performance isn't a concern then this solution would work. You would also need to provide replacements for PrintWriter.print and PrintWriter.printf if you wish to use them.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to replace the out and err streams with a stream that outputs to nothing.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        System.setOut( new PrintStream( new ByteArrayOutputStream() ) );

        System.out.println( "Won't print anything." );

        System.setOut( out );

        System.out.println( "Will print out." );
    }
}
```

The same thing can be done for System.err. Remember to keep a reference to the only System.out or you may lose access to stdout.

This solution replaces the out stream to print to a ByteArrayOutputStream, which can use a lot of memory if you are printing a lot of characters. A better solution would be to create an OutputStream that ignores everything written to it. Similar to /dev/null.

Example of a NullOutputStream

```
public class NullOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    public void write( int b ) throws IOException {}

    public void write( byte[] b, int s, int l ) throws IOException {}

}
```

It's not necessary to override write( byte[], int, int ) but for performance reasons it should be done otherwise there will be l calls to write( int );

Comment: +1, although while this is technically valid, and in some cases preferred, the OP's goal is to deal with the type system in this.

Comment: I've retracted my upvote for now, as I've realized that this carries a memory penalty as `ByteArrayOutputStream` records all output to an internal byte array, carrying a memory penalty. An implementation of `PrintStream` that no-ops on writes should be used.

Comment: @hexafraction this is why I added the last part about creating a null OutputStream that ignores all data written to it. Also his question was about how to silence output using something similar to templates in C++, but this solution is faster than using one that autoboxes all data into Objects.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that when I skimmed this. +1 restored. Thanks!

Comment: That was my bad. I didn't add that at first, and it probably wasn't there when you were reading through.

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally possible to translate such short pieces of C++ into idiomatic Java.

You may want to use an interface in place of `T` (the objects you pass to the method must implement the interface).

You might also be looking for something like log4j.